# Chartist.js displaying tool tips in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, chartist.js

I'm working on a chartists project and I'm attempting to display tools. I've spent all day on this and cannot seem to get it. The main issue is in the Chartist.plugins.tooltip method that simply does not do anything on the screen. I've wondered if it's a css issue which can be seen in the styles below. Also, I've tried numerous NPM packages and nothing seemed to work. Any help would be great. Here is the code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <VueChartist
        type="Line"
        :data="data"
        :options="options" >
    </VueChartist>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import VueChartist from 'v-chartist';
import Chartist from 'chartist';
import * as MyLegend from 'chartist-plugin-axistitle';
import ChartistTooltip from 'chartist-plugin-tooltips-updated';


export default {
    name: "ChartTwo",
    components: {
        'VueChartist': VueChartist
    },
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                series: [
                    [2, 3, 2, 4, 5],
                    [4, 2.5, 3, 2, 1],
                    [1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 4]
            ]
        },
            options: {
                width: 600,
                height: 600,
                high: 5,
                low: 1,
                // divisor: 2,
                ticks: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
                plugins: [
                    Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle({
                        axisX: {
                            axisTitle: "Days of the Week",
                            offset: {
                                x: 10,
                                y: 30
                            },
                            scaleMinSpace: 2,
                            labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
                               return index % 2 === 0 ? value : null;
                            },
                        },
                        axisY: {
                            axisTitle: "Grades",
                        }
                    }),
                     Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
                ]//End of plugins

            }//End of options 
         }
      }// End of Data object 
   }//End of Vue Instance 
 </script>

  <style>
    .ct-series-a .ct-line {
       /* Set the colour of this series line */
       stroke: blue;
       /* Control the thickness of your lines */
       stroke-width: 5px;
      /* Create a dashed line with a pattern */
      stroke-dasharray: 10px 20px;
    }

        .chartist-tooltip {
           opacity: 0;
           position: absolute;
           margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
           background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
           color: #FFF;
           padding: 5px 10px;
           border-radius: 4px;
       }

      .chartist-tooltip.tooltip-show {
         opacity: 1;
      }

      .ct-chart .ct-bar {
        stroke-width: 40px;
      }
   </style>
```

What I would like is both the labels and series displayed on the screen when I hover over a point in a tooltip. I know that this can be done but an afternoon reading documentation and I've barely made progress on it. Again, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I've just face the same problem and after few research i end up with this:

```
--Instalation
    npm i chartist-plugin-tooltips
--import
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import 'chartist/dist/chartist.min.css'
    import * as ChartistTooltips from 'chartist-plugin-tooltips';

    Vue.use(require('vue-chartist'), {
        messageNoData: "You have not enough data",
        classNoData: "empty"
    })
--On component
plugins: [
            this.$chartist.plugins.tooltip({
              anchorToPoint:true,
              appendToBody: true
            })
          ]
--CSS for better looks and show only on hover
.chartist-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    min-width: 5em;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    background: #383838;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: opacity .2s linear;
  }

  .chartist-tooltip:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(251, 249, 228, 0);
    border-top-color: #383838;
    border-width: 7px;
    margin-left: -8px;
  }

  .chartist-tooltip.tooltip-show {
      display: inline-block !important;
  }
```